# Draw smiley face ASCII art

Tags: c#

This is so trivial it's going to sound silly, but please bear with me.

I used to be able to draw ASCII art smiley faces [similar to this post](http://www.programmingposts.com/2013/02/c-program-to-print-smiling-face.html) by doing something like:

```
Console.Write((char)1);
```

Back when I did this on Windows XP/7, the console was not able to render the character by default. I got around this encoding issue by using this special encoding:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Now that I'm trying this out in Windows 10, I am getting this weird question mark character which is reminiscent of the original encoding problem:

[image]

Has something changed in the Windows 10 console to cause this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Open a console, hold Alt, type NumPad-1, release Alt. In Windows 7 I get the smiley. What do you get in Windows 10?

Comment: I get the smiley too. That rules out OS differences.

Comment: The OS difference is that you have TrueType fonts in the console on Windows 10 and Raster Fonts (which force the OEM character set) on legacy Windows versions. The fact that it worked before was merely a lucky combinations of circumstances, not the fact that you did the right thing to make a smiley appear.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `(char)1` would *only* work with the OEM codepage 437. This worked well in DOS applications, but on Windows the approach is slightly trickier, especially since U+0001 does *not* represent a smiley face. U+263A does. So the correct way is actually:

```
Console.WriteLine((char)0x263A);
```

And you may have to explicitly set your output encoding to Unicode, or UTF-8 to make it show up, otherwise the character passes through a few character set translations along the way, depending on your console window settings:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
```

Comment: Why are you casting 0x263A to a char? Why not just use `"☺"`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Because it can be entered by anyone. Because it survives regardless of the file encoding. Because the author used that format as well and there's little need to make the diff to their code larger than necessary. `'\u263A'` would be better, though, but I do enough of those character code stuff in PowerShell that I didn't think of that at first.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Windows 10:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Console.WriteLine("☺");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Unicode character

```
char c = '\u263a';
Console.WriteLine (c.ToString());
```

[Working Example Here](https://repl.it/Co43/0)