# Write a program to fill the entire screen with a smiling face. The smiling face has an ASCII value 1

Tags: c, character, ascii, special-characters

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output: program ended with exit code:0
I'm getting this output when running on Xcode. what should i do?

Comment: 'The smiling face has an ASCII value 1' There is no "smiling face" in ASCII. The character with the value 1 is the Start Of Heading control code and is normally not a printable character.

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout); getchar();` before the return statement.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39013531/2513200

Comment: In other words - this used to "work" in old versions of DOS and Windows (and may still work on some systems), but it depends on OS settings regarding the character set used to render the output.

Comment: IIRC one of the "extended ASCII" MS DOS symbol tables had a smiling face at 1, followed by spades, clubs, heart, diamonds and other weird stuff.

Comment: My Windows 10 commandline still displays them like that.

Comment: If you run the program in a Win32 console, you will probably see the "smiling face" characters, but I don't know what sort of terminal Xcode uses. On a Linux pseudo terminal, the printed `'\1'` characters have no visible effect on the display.

Comment: Oh yeah it's still there. I got this from printing 0 to 32 `☺☻♥♦♣
♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼`

Comment: These days, if you want to display any special characters like that, unicode is the way to go. Check out https://unicode-table.com for an exhaustive list. You can print them with `"\uXXX"`, where XXX is the codepoint (like `\u2615` for a cup of coffee)

Answer (score 1):

> "*output: program ended with exit code:0. I'm getting this output when running on Xcode. what should I do?*"

This is not a proper output of the program itself. It means the program terminated successfully without any occurrence of an error.

Regarding your assignment, it is not possible to print a smiling face with the *ASCII* value `1`, as in any regular ASCII set, it is a control character for "Start of Heading", means not printable.

The smiling face symbol for 1 belongs to an extended character set for MS DOS-consoles only. If the printing of 1 gets you no visible output, your terminal uses the standard ASCII character set and with printing 1 you actually trigger `SOH` (Start of Heading).

If you want to print a smiling face, use the respective Unicode-string of `"\u263A"` instead:

```
printf("%s", "\u263A");
```

Note the change from `%c` to `%s` to print a string.

Also you need f.e. two nested loops to fill the whole screen instead of just a line, if the terminal doesn´t adjust the output to the terminal.

---

Result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i <= 70; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 50; j++)
        {
            printf("%s", "\u263A");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output (truncated):

```
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check what is your character set.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int ch = 1; ch < 256; ch++)
    {
        printf("code %d \t\t%c\n", ch, ch);
    }
}
```

for example the godbolt OS and toolchain https://godbolt.org/z/3g_VE5

Comment: suggestion... `#include <limits.h>` and `for (int ch = CHAR_MIN; ch <= CHAR_MAX; ch++) { /* ... */ }`